# GET request to googleapis

Tags: cordova, get, youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

I am using the Cordova HTTP plugin to perform a HTTP GET request to googleapis server.

Currently I perform this type of request through a browser and it works:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={myKey}&channelId={mychannel}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

Now I want to perform this call through the plugin.
I tried this request

```
  cordovaHTTP.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?", {
key: "mykey",
channelId: "mychannel",
part: "snippet,id",
order: "date"

}, { Authorization: "OAuth2: token" }, 
function(response) {
    alert(response.status);
}, function(response) {
    alert(response.error);
});
```

although I get an authError due to Invalid Credentials.
How is the correct way to perform the GET request?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved. I removed the authorization line (Authorization: "OAuth2: token").
This is the correct GET request:

```
cordovaHTTP.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?", {
key: "mykey",
channelId: "mychannel",
part: "snippet,id",
order: "date"

}, { }, 
function(response) {
    alert(response.status);
}, function(response) {
    alert(response.error);
});
```